# Custom script working wrong in Blazor server side

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have Blazor Server side project with MudBlazor first, components working fine (I focus on text field).
Then I add Black Dashboard template (https://www.creative-tim.com/product/black-dashboard) into my project. And issue come.

Here's my _Host.cshtml

```
@page "/"
@namespace PPJ_Internal_Website_BlazorServer.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>PPJ_Internal_Website_BlazorServer</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />*@
    <link href="PPJ_Internal_Website_BlazorServer.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="assets/css/nucleo-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/black-dashboard.css?v=1.0.0" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
    @*<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"></script>*@
    <script src="assets/js/plugins/chartjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/black-dashboard.min.js?v=1.0.0"></script>
    @*<script src="js/customjs.js"></script>*@
    <script src="https://cdn.trackjs.com/agent/v3/latest/t.js"></script>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $().ready(function () {
                $sidebar = $('.sidebar');
                $navbar = $('.navbar');
                $main_panel = $('.main-panel');

                $full_page = $('.full-page');

                $sidebar_responsive = $('body > .navbar-collapse');
                sidebar_mini_active = true;
                white_color = false;

                window_width = $(window).width();

                fixed_plugin_open = $('.sidebar .sidebar-wrapper .nav li.active a p').html();



                $('.fixed-plugin a').click(function (event) {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('switch-trigger')) {
                        if (event.stopPropagation) {
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        } else if (window.event) {
                            window.event.cancelBubble = true;
                        }
                    }
                });

                $('.fixed-plugin .background-color span').click(function () {
                    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');

                    var new_color = $(this).data('color');

                    if ($sidebar.length != 0) {
                        $sidebar.attr('data', new_color);
                    }

                    if ($main_panel.length != 0) {
                        $main_panel.attr('data', new_color);
                    }

                    if ($full_page.length != 0) {
                        $full_page.attr('filter-color', new_color);
                    }

                    if ($sidebar_responsive.length != 0) {
                        $sidebar_responsive.attr('data', new_color);
                    }
                });

                $('.switch-sidebar-mini input').on("switchChange.bootstrapSwitch", function () {
                    var $btn = $(this);

                    if (sidebar_mini_active == true) {
                        $('body').removeClass('sidebar-mini');
                        sidebar_mini_active = false;
                        blackDashboard.showSidebarMessage('Sidebar mini deactivated...');
                    } else {
                        $('body').addClass('sidebar-mini');
                        sidebar_mini_active = true;
                        blackDashboard.showSidebarMessage('Sidebar mini activated...');
                    }

                    // we simulate the window Resize so the charts will get updated in realtime.
                    var simulateWindowResize = setInterval(function () {
                        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
                    }, 180);

                    // we stop the simulation of Window Resize after the animations are completed
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        clearInterval(simulateWindowResize);
                    }, 1000);
                });

                $('.switch-change-color input').on("switchChange.bootstrapSwitch", function () {
                    var $btn = $(this);

                    if (white_color == true) {

                        $('body').addClass('change-background');
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('body').removeClass('change-background');
                            $('body').removeClass('white-content');
                        }, 900);
                        white_color = false;
                    } else {

                        $('body').addClass('change-background');
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('body').removeClass('change-background');
                            $('body').addClass('white-content');
                        }, 900);

                        white_color = true;
                    }


                });

                $('.light-badge').click(function () {
                    $('body').addClass('white-content');
                });

                $('.dark-badge').click(function () {
                    $('body').removeClass('white-content');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Javascript method's body can be found in assets/js/demos.js
            demo.initDashboardPageCharts();

        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.trackjs.com/agent/v3/latest/t.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.TrackJS &&
            TrackJS.install({
                token: "ee6fab19c5a04ac1a32a645abde4613a",
                application: "black-dashboard-free"
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I remove `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>`, my custom script tag is working fine, I can change theme, sidbar background but MudBlazor text field working not good.
[image]
When I add `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>`, Mud component working good, but custom scripts don't work, I can't change sidebar background or theme.
[image]

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Blazor doesn’t interact with JavaScript the same way that server-side rendered pages do. Components only redraw when Blazor can tell the state has changed (and has various automatic and manual ways of invoking this). That is why when Blazor server js is left out it works and doesn’t when included.

You either need to invoke those JavaScript functions manually by wiring up your own methods that invoke them, write your own Blazor code that does it for you, or find a library with parity functionality.